# How to find the number of elements of a float array in python and how to convert it to a 2-dimensional float array?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to find the length of a 1-D float array and convert it into a 2-d array in python. Also when I am trying to print the elements of the float array the following error is coming:-
***'float' object is not iterable***

Comment: show the code please

Answer (score 0):

Length of array: `len(array)`. Try to do 2 cycles to spread all values to 2-d array.